# mongoDB/mongoose: Text search does not work on searches of two or less characters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model I want to perform a text search on with mongoose.

`let models = await MyModel.find({$text: {$search: '"go"'}});`

However, I have noticed when I search for strings with two or less characters no results are returned.

How can I search for strings with two or less characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `aggregate` query and `RegEx`, as follows:

```
let searchText = "go";
searchText = new RegExp(searchText, "i");

let models = await MyModel.aggregate([ {$match: {"text": { $regex: searchText}}} ])
```

here `text` is the field on which search will be applied. You can add `$or` conditions to search in more than one field.

Comment: What would the performance implications of this be? Additionally, I'm assuming this would remove the ability from `$search` to use quotes for an exact match and minus to exclude terms, which I would like to keep.

Comment: Aggregate does not cause any performance issue as such. Anyway regarding your query of trying to search with two or less `searchText` I do not think that should be an issue unless you do not have any record matching the criteria. Also if you are trying to accomplish partial searches that will not be possible using the `$search` and you will have to use regex. Also if you want to exclude terms you can use the regex to do those.